# passing statically typed input to tensorflow serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

In tensorflow documentation it says that predict request should have `instances` arguments holding in the model inputs features as list with importance of order.
is there a way to pass the list of inputs to the served model as json, instead of plain list?
i.e :

```json
"instances": 
{ "my-feature":1.0,
  "my-next-feature":"foo"
}
```

ins

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.keras` like this :

```
input1 = tf.keras.Input(name="my-feature", dtype=tf.float32)
input2 = tf.keras.Input(name="my-next-feature", dtype=str)
...
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input1,input2],outputs=xxx)
```

Then you could use tfs like what you want:

```
{ 
  "my-feature":1.0,
  "my-next-feature":"foo"
}
```

If you have more complex demand , you can try `tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing` . Read https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers for more detail .

Answer (score 0):

Let's check what the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest) says:

```
{
  // (Optional) Serving signature to use.
  // If unspecifed default serving signature is used.
  "signature_name": <string>,

  // Input Tensors in row ("instances") or columnar ("inputs") format.
  // A request can have either of them but NOT both.
  "instances": <value>|<(nested)list>|<list-of-objects>
  "inputs": <value>|<(nested)list>|<object>
}
```

So that should work:

```json
{
  "signature_name": "serving_default",
  "instances":
    [
      {
        "my-feature": 1.0,
        "my-next-feature": "foo"
      },
      {
        "my-feature": 2.0,
        "my-next-feature": "bar"
      }
    ]
}
```